# How to refresh/keep token activated for Mobile Apps

Tags: mobile, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

As far as web applications are concerned I know I can refresh/reissue the JWT by setting another parameter expireUntil in JWT with some duration and check it in each subsequent request and if it's not expire I can reissue the token or something along those lines. I don't know how efficient it is or if it's the right approach but that's the one I had in mind. Secondly I could also do it on the front-end by keep looking at the expiry time and resend the request to reissue it if it's about to expire. Anyway, the idea is to not let the user sign off if it's continuously making requests like in old session era.

Apart from that, the major question is how mobile application keeps the token alive forever. I don't think I was ever signed out of my Uber or foodpanda app even if I'm offline for days. How do they do it in case of mobile apps? Do they simply set the token expiry to some really large arbitrary value or some other way to authenticate and reissue the token because I know I can't do that with the approach I listed in above paragraph as if the user remains offline for a day my token will expire.

Any ideas how can I do that?